# C+Ctrl KeyBinding is not causing copying to happen

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I have set up a `ListBox` like so:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="logListView">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}">
                <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="C"
                                Modifiers="Ctrl"
                                Command="Copy"/>
                </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                <TextBlock.CommandBindings>
                    <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                                    Executed="KeyCopyLog_Executed"
                                    CanExecute="CopyLog_CanExecute"/>
                </TextBlock.CommandBindings>
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="Copy">
                            <MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                                <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                                                Executed="MenuCopyLog_Executed"
                                                CanExecute="CopyLog_CanExecute"/>
                            </MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see, in the template, each `TextBlock` has a context menu that allows the user to copy the text. This works.

Also in the `TextBlock` there is an `KeyBinding` to <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> and a `CommandBinding` to copy. When I press <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> the method `KeyCopyLog_Executed` is not executed. I've checked with the debugger.

How should I be binding the keys to the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pavlov Glazkov for explaining that the key and command bindings need to go at the `ListBox` level, rather than the item template level.

This is the solution I now have:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C"
                    Modifiers="Ctrl"
                    Command="Copy"/>
    </ListBox.InputBindings>
    <ListBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        Executed="KeyCopyLog_Executed"
                        CanExecute="CopyLog_CanExecute"/>
    </ListBox.CommandBindings>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=.}">
                <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="Copy">
                            <MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                                <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                                                Executed="MenuCopyLog_Executed"
                                                CanExecute="CopyLog_CanExecute"/>
                            </MenuItem.CommandBindings>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where `KeyCopyLog_Executed` is:

```
private void KeyCopyLog_Executed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem != null)
    {
        LogItem item = (LogItem) (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;
        Clipboard.SetData("Text", item.ToString());
    }
}
```

and `MenuCopyLog_Executed` is:

```
private void MenuCopyLog_Executed(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LogItem item = (LogItem) ((sender as MenuItem).TemplatedParent as ContentPresenter).DataContext;
    Clipboard.SetData("Text", item.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 12):

There are a couple of problems here.

First of all, `KeyBindings` will work only if currently focused element is located **inside** the element where KeyBindings are defined. In your case you have a `ListBoxItem` focused, but the `KeyBindings` are defined on the child element - `TextBlock`. So, defining a `KeyBindings` on a `TextBlock` will not work in any case, since a TextBlock cannot receive focus.

Second of all, you probably need to know what to copy, so you need to pass the currently selected log item as parameter to the `Copy` command.

Furthermore, if you define a `ContextMenu` on a `TextBlock` element it will be opened only if your right-click exactly on the `TextBlock`. If you click on any other part of the list item, it will not open. So, you need to define the `ContextMenu` on the list box item itself.

Considering all of that, what I believe you are trying to do can be done in the following way:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=OneWay}"
         x:Name="logListView"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="C"
                    Modifiers="Ctrl"
                    Command="Copy"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Logs/}" />
    </ListBox.InputBindings>

    <ListBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Copy"
                        Executed="CopyLogExecuted"
                        CanExecute="CanExecuteCopyLog" />
    </ListBox.CommandBindings>

    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="Copy"
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here we define a `KeyBinding` on the `ListBox` itself and specify as a `CommandParameter` currently selected list box item (log entry).

`CommandBinding` is also defined at the `ListBox` level and it is a single binding for both right click menu and the keyboard shortcut.

The `ContextMenu` we define in the style for `ListBoxItem` and bind `CommandParameter` to the data item represented by this `ListBoxItem` (log entry).

The `DataTemplate` just declares a `TextBlock` with binding to current data item.

And finally, there is only one handler for the `Copy` command in the code-behind:

```
private void CopyLogExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    var logItem = e.Parameter;

    // Copy log item to the clipboard
}

private void CanExecuteCopyLog(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't tested it yet, but I will when I'm back at work. Currently, to get the log entry I want to copy, I am getting the `DataContext` of the `TemplatedParent` of the sender in the event handler. It works for the `MenuItem`. I will try your method though, as it seems simpler.

Comment: I have given the above code a go. Is this for .Net 3.5? I can't get it to work, and I am limited to .Net 3.5. The problems it is throwing up are: Can't use bindings in `CommandParameter` properties, can't set the value of a `ContextMenu` property to be a `MenuItem` object in a style block.

Comment: I have merged my initial way of doing things with your in a way that works. I'll post an answer with it in.

Comment: @Matt Ellen - This code is for .NET 4. But you can fix the issues you mentioned by removing CommandParameter bindings all together. Instead, just bind ListBox's SelectedItem property to some property on your data context (e.g. SelectedLogItem) and use this property in CopyLogExecuted handler to get item to copy.